# Multiple 400 response example on Swagger with Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

Tags: .net-core, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I use Swashbuckle.AspNetCore library to generate Swagger documentation. Is it possible to add multiple error messages to one status code? For example I have field which has validations so I need this in my documentation:

```
Code   Description
 400   Invalid format
       Field is required
       Should be greater than 10
```

In previous version of library we had `[SwaggerResponse]` where I could put validation errors into description, but the attribute is not available in newest version. We have `[ProducesResponseType]` attribute which doesn't have description parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters](https://github.com/mattfrear/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters) to specify multiple examples.

1. See this section for how to enable filters: [Installation](https://github.com/mattfrear/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters#how-to-use---multiple-examples)
   I specifically only added `c.ExampleFilters()` and `services.AddSwaggerExamplesFromAssemblies(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly())` to my `Startup.cs`.
2. See this section for how to create multiple examples: [Multiple Example Setup](https://github.com/mattfrear/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters#how-to-use---multiple-examples)
3. See this section for usage details: [Using Multiple Examples](https://github.com/mattfrear/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters#how-to-use---multiple-examples)
   The document mentions the use of `SwaggerResponse` and `SwaggerResponseExample`  annotation but I was able to achieve desired result with only using `SwaggerResponseExample`.